# download multiple .xlsx files from multiple url-pages in R

Tags: r

Trying to download multiple pages .xlsx into R from this url.

https://niti.gov.in/best-practices/district-wise-statistics

Have read in the url and can download one page at a time but want to import all pages at once.

```
pg <- read_html("https://niti.gov.in/best-practices/district-wise-statistics/")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_subset("\\.xlsx")
```

Comment: What have you tried? What package(s) are you using?

Comment: pg <- read_html("https://niti.gov.in/best-practices/district-wise-statistics/")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_subset("\\.xlsx")

Comment: Code in comments is discouraged for a couple of reasons: first, it can be hard to read; second, comments are easily skipped by readers and/or hidden when there are lots of comments. Please just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56873656/edit) and insert the code into a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Further, those are not base functions, please include non-base packages you are using (I'm inferring `xml2`, `magrittr`, `rvest`, and `stringr`, please confirm and include them in your question).

Comment: More the point: while comments help build a dialog, a question should be complete in-and-of-itself, meaning code/data/description. It's not uncommon to have 3 or more edits as you address questions/clarifications from others.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work to get you what you need.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

temp.fldr <- paste0(tempdir(), '/')

base.url <- 'https://niti.gov.in/best-practices/district-wise-statistics'

last <- read_html(base.url) %>%
         html_nodes(xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'last ')]") %>%
         html_attr('href')

pg.cnt = as.numeric(sub('.*=', '', last))

for(i in 0:pg.cnt){
  page <- paste0(base.url, '?term_node_tid_depth=All&page=', i)
  print(paste('Processing page:', i + 1, 'of', pg.cnt + 1))

  links <- read_html(page) %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'xlsx')]")

  files <- lapply(links, function(x){
             fpath <- paste0(temp.fldr, trimws(sub("^.*?\\.", '', html_text(x))))
             link <- paste0('https://niti.gov.in', html_attr(x, 'href'))
             download.file(link, fpath, mode = 'wb')
             print(fpath)
             return(fpath)
           })
}
```

Comment: Setting `xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'xlsx')]"` in `html_nodes()` may get you to the Excel files a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. Is there another way to count the number of pages. It's just returning NA which then causes an error in the loop. Thank you again a million for the help.

Comment: I've edited the code to modify how I'm grabbing the last page, and also implemented the suggestion from @seasmith when grabbing the nodes to improve the performance.